# Unable to fetch the records on TO DATE Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, plsql

Database - Table

```
 PROD.APPLICATION 
Game ID    Generated Date

 1          Jan-01-1995
 2          Aug-19-2003
 3          Nov-04-2001
 4          Sep-26-2007
 5          Sep-26-2007
 6          Sep-26-2007
 7          Sep-19-2007
 8          Sep-19-2007
 9          Sep-19-2007
10          Jan-11-1985
11          MAY-19-2003
12          Sep-22-2007
13          Sep-22-2007
```

I ran the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM PROD.APPLICATION JOIN PROD.STATUS ON (PROD.STATUS_ID = REF_STATUS.STATUS_ID)  

AND PROD.APPLICATION.GENERETED_DT >= to_date('2007-09-19', 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND     
    PROD.APPLICATION.GENERETED_DT <= to_date('2007-09-26', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

to search for the records from  Sep 19 2007 to Sep 26 2007  ie 8 records.

Which has resulted in showing the only records  for Sep 19 2007 znd Sep 22 2007 ie only 5 records

```
Actual Output
Game ID    Generated Date
7 Sep-19-2007
8 Sep-19-2007
9 Sep-19-2007
12 Sep-22-2007
13 Sep-22-2007
```

How to generate the search query so that I could get all the 8 records -   ie the records on those dates aswell

Expected Output

```
 4 Sep-26-2007
 5 Sep-26-2007
 6 Sep-26-2007
 7 Sep-19-2007
 8 Sep-19-2007
 9 Sep-19-2007
12 Sep-22-2007
13 Sep-22-2007
```

Tried

```
SELECT *
FROM PROD.APPLICATION JOIN PROD.STATUS ON (PROD.STATUS_ID = REF_STATUS.STATUS_ID)  

AND PROD.APPLICATION.GENERETED_DT >= to_date('2007-09-19', 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND     
    PROD.APPLICATION.GENERETED_DT = to_date('2007-09-26', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Revived No records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date probably has a time component.  This is part of the `date` data type in Oracle -- but is often not shown when you query.

A better approach uses the following logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM PROD.APPLICATION A JOIN
     PROD.STATUS S
     ON A.STATUS_ID = S.STATUS_ID  
WHERE A.GENERATED_DT >= DATE '2007-09-19' AND
      A.GENERATED_DT < DATE '2007-09-27';
```

Notes:

- The `< DATE '2007-09-27'` will include all datetimes from the day before.
- The `DATE` keyword introduces a date constants with the format YYYY-MM-DD.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Moving the condition to the `WHERE` clause has no effect on the query, but such filtering is more commonly done in the `WHERE` clause for an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: If your input "end date" needs to be a variable you can also add one to it.
myEndDate + 1, or in OP's original sample: to_date('2007-09-26', 'yyyy-MM-dd') + 1 This adds a full 24 hour day to the date type.

Answer (score 1):

This truncates the time part in APPLICATION.GENERETED_DT and then compares it to the date on the right side.

```
SELECT *
FROM PROD.APPLICATION JOIN PROD.STATUS ON (PROD.STATUS_ID = REF_STATUS.STATUS_ID)  
AND trunc(PROD.APPLICATION.GENERETED_DT) >= to_date('2007-09-19', 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND     
    trunc(PROD.APPLICATION.GENERETED_DT) <= to_date('2007-09-26', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```